# parallel processing of python script

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, gnu-parallel

I have a python script which takes one input at a time and process it . 
I want to run script parallel with different inputs at a same time . Like 50 or 100 times but with different inputs feed from txt file .

i execute script like:

```
python script.py -d url1
```

then

```
python script.py -d url2
```

then

```
python script.py -d url3
```

and instead of input one argument at a time , i want to feed those url from a text file and process them in parallel .

I tried this script running in bash shell using gnu-parallel but bash script not runs python shell and thus errors.

the code is as follows---

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
doit() {
    host="$1"
    ~/script/python script1.py -d $host
      }
   export -f doit

   cat "$1" | parallel -j50 -k doit
```

contents of txt file---

```
url1.com
url2.com
url3.com
--------
url1000.com
url_any.com
```

Comment: I downvoted because it seems no research attempt was made.

Comment: i tried to run it with with gnu parallel but before ,  i run parallel in bash script like go language accepts  but this needs shell in python and thus i can't able to run it .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With **GNU Parallel**, like this:

```
parallel --dry-run -a arguments.txt python script.py
```

which assumes your arguments are one per line in `"arguments.txt"`.

Use `parallel -k ...` to keep outputs in order, if required.

Use `parallel --bar ...` to get a progress bar.

Comment: python script itself takes argument like "python script1.py -d abc"

Comment: Not sure I understand. Just add any parameters you need at the end. Please click `edit` under your question and show 3 lines of your `"arguments.txt"` file and then show the 3 corresponding commands that should be executed.

Comment: i tried your code and it just output the text required command rather then executing that paricular command like "
python script.py - d any.com "

Comment: If the output looks correct, run it again but without `--dry-run` which is for debugging.

Comment: yeah its working , can it take like -j50 or -j100 like argument to control input.

Comment: Yes, `-j 50` means *"run 50 jobs in parallel at a time"*. Try `man parallel` to see all options.

Comment: Notice at the moment, that a whole Python interpreter must be fired up and executed for each and every line of your file. In general, you would do better to change your script so that it can look at its parameters and process a whole list of filenames/hostnames or whatever they are. Then you can run `parallel -X ...` and it will maybe fire up just 8 Python interpreters in parallel and each one can maybe process 20,000 files before exiting. That is MUCH faster, normally.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to **GNU Parallel** is to use Python **subprocess** to execute the command repeatedly.

This is an example using Python 2.7.

First your code will need to read the text file to assign all the arguments to a list.

```
with open('<Arguments text file location>') as f:
    arguments = f.read().splitlines()
```

Then you use a loop to run the command once for each argument using subprocess.

```
import subprocess
procs = []
for argument in arguments:
    cmd = 'python script.py %(argument)' % {'argument': argument}
    procs.append(
        subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
    )
exit_codes = [p.wait() for p in procs]
```

Comment: if no. of arguments are say 1000, this would create 1000 shell processes right?
is that a thing to worry about? 
Is there any limit to no of sub processes we can spawn without crashing anything?

Comment: AFAIK the limit is your CPU and memory. You need to do some benchmarking for that.